# How to remove a certain character at a certain position that is not a index?

Tags: java, string

For example lets say you have the string "greg". The program prompts you to enter which character to remove and you say "g", the program then prompts "Enter the g you would like to remove (Not the index - 1 = 1st, 2 = 2nd, etc.)" and you enter "2". The program then outputs the new sentence which is "gre". This is a piece of my program for my CSCI class and I know how to do it using replace(), but my professors says we can only use loops and these string methods length, concat, +, charAt, substring, and equals (or equalsIgnoreCase). I can't seem to figure it out any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 1) loop through the characters in the string; keep a separate counter for the letter you're looking for (let's call it `count_l`); 2) check if the letter from current iteration is the one you're looking for; if it is increase `count_l`; 3) if `count_l` corresponds to the number from the user, you found your letter. Use `substring` to take the parts before and after it and return the new string by joining them.

Comment: You ask a char, determine the occurrenceCount, if > 1 ask ithOccurrence. Then loop through the string's characters. till the ithOccurrence's char is encountered. Printing the rest of the string upto that position.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you so much!

Comment: @RishiDesai posted an answer with 2 scenarios , is that what wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, you need to maintain count for number of occurrences and build a new string skipping nth occurence(Strings are immutable in Java):

```
public static String removeNthCharacter(String input, char ch, int occurence) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int totalOccurences = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == ch) {
            totalOccurences++;
            if (totalOccurences == occurence) {
                // Skip This character
                continue;
            }
        }
        sb.append(input.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I tested this and it seems to generate expected output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeNthCharacter("greg", 'g', 2));
    System.out.println(removeNthCharacter("greggggeegeegggg", 'g', 6));
}
```

This produces this output:

```
src : $ java RemoveChar 
gre
greggggeeeegggg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter character to be removed : ");
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char character = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Possible positions of "+character+" : ");
    
    // find all occurrences forward
    for (int i = -1; (i = input.indexOf(character, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    
    System.out.print("Select any above index to remove : ");
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int index = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Result : "+input.substring(0, index)+input.substring(index+1, input.length()));
}
```

**output**

```
Enter a String : greg
Enter character to be removed : g
Possible positions of g : 
0
3
Select any above index to remove : 0
Result : reg
```

**output**

```
Enter a String : greg
Enter character to be removed : g
Possible positions of g : 
0
3
Select any above index to remove : 3
Result : gre
```